# Control function call using user input : Batch

Tags: batch-file

I would like to write a batch file which works as per the input received from the user but on my code it always calls the "AddingFile" function.

```
@ECHO off

ECHO Select [A] Adding File [R] Remove File [C] Copy File [E] Close Program.

GOTO:startCompile


:startCompile
::CLS

SET /p select = Make a selection. 

IF "%select%"=="1" ( goto addingFileObject )
IF "%select%"=="2" ( goto removeFileObject )
IF "%select%"=="3" ( goto copy )
IF "%select%"=="4" ( goto defaultExit )

:addingFile
ECHO "Adding files"
goto:EOF

:removeFile
ECHO "Remove files"
goto:EOF

:defaultExit
pause
goto:EOF

:copy
ECHO "Copying Filed"
goto:EOF
```

Comment: Remote the space from `SET /p select<space>=`. And you need a `goto :eof` after your `IF-Block`

Comment: if i use `goto:eof` after `IF-BLOCK-` it directly exit the code with out executing any of the function.

Comment: Currently execution continues at the `:addingFile` section when your selection is anything else than `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, so you should at least define some default behaviour in such a case, like `goto :`defaultExit`, for example. Anyway, take a look at the [`choice` command](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html), which does not allow the user to enter anything else then the predefined choices...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code contains two bugs.

The line `SET /P select<space>=...` is wrong or at least produces unexpected behaviour.
It sets a variable named `select<space>` therefore the access via `%select%` will always fail.

An `exit /b` or `goto :eof` is missing after the block of `IF` commands, that results in incorrect behaviour when none of the IF-compares are true.
Then the addingFile part will be executed.

Btw. Such problems can simply be debugged with `ECHO ON`.
In this case it would show the second problem by these lines, the `%select%` is always empty

```
...
c:\Temp>IF "" == "1" (goto addingFileObject  )
c:\Temp>IF "" == "2" (goto removeFileObject  )
c:\Temp>IF "" == "3" (goto copy  )
c:\Temp>IF "" == "4" (goto defaultExit  )
```

Answer (score 3):

…and using the more appropriate `Choice` command:

```bat
@Echo Off
Choice /C ARCE /N /M "Select [A]dd [R]emove [C]opy or [E]xit"
If ErrorLevel 4 GoTo :EOF
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo copy
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo removeFile

Echo "Adding files"
Timeout 2 /NoBreak>Nul
Exit /B

:removeFile
Echo "Remove files"
Timeout 2 /NoBreak>Nul
Exit /B

:copy
Echo "Copying Files"
Timeout 2 /NoBreak>Nul
```